# pass form values in managed bean

Tags: java, jsf, managed-bean

i want to pass my form value into my managed bean in order to process it but i always got a null value when i try to retrieve the value in my action method

My bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="datas")
@SessionScoped

public class Datas implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String ID_primary;

    public Datas(){

    }

    public Datas (String ID_primary){   
        this.ID_primary=ID_primary;
    }
    public String getID_primary() {
        return ID_primary;
    }
    public void setID_primary(String ID_primary) {
        this.ID_primary= ID_primary;
    }

    public void process() {

        Map<String, String> request=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

        String value = request.get("ID_primary"); // always return null
        System.out.println("ID" + value);

    }
}
```

My form

```
<h:form>
    <div align="left">                      
            <h:inputText id="ID_primary" name="ID_primary" value="#{datas.ID_primary}" />                           
    </div>
    ..........


    <div align="right">

                <h:commandButton action="#{datas.process()}" value="Create" type="submit" />
  </div>
</h:form>
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different `form` elements, when you click `commandButton` in the bottom `form`, values from the top `form` are not send with the request.

You can have tags like `div` inside a `form`, so you can make on big `form` with `div`s  inside if it is the reason why you have have split them.

Also add `@ManagedProperty` annotation to `ID_primary` field:

```
public class Datas implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{Datas.ID_primary}")
    private String ID_primary;
    [..]
```

EDIT:

Ok, my bad, I have not looked at the code carefully. In `ManagedBean` with `ManagedProperty` this property will be set automatically by JSF, so you can read it like this:

```
public void process() {
        System.out.println("ID" + getID_primary());
}
```

Comment: thank you very much . I changed the form but i still got null value from it :( .

Comment: thank you very much but i have still null value . When i go in debug mode , i see that my external context contains nothing , so the problem is perhaps here

Comment: thank you very much . You saved my life my friend :) . It works good now with the managedProperty and getter . I was obsessed with the ExternalContext way which didn t worked . It 's much easier with your way . Thank you again